# Unable to use Tagging and excluding Filters

Tags: solr, filter, tagging

I have 2 Facets color and shape.

Color:
   Red
   Green
   yellow

Shape:
   Circle
   Square

Now I want to use Tagging and excluding Filters for both these Facet.
So if I select "Red" the green and yellow should be present in facet list and all shapes as well

I read:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters

But unable to implement it in my setup.

Comment: Can you post your schema.xml, some sample documents and the query you are issuing?

Comment: Schema.xml:<br/>
Color and Shape are 2 string variable (indexed and searchable).<br/>

Query:<br/>
I wanted to what query I should Form to get the above results mention in my question. I am using default browse that comes with solr<br/>
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/browse<br/>


Document are records from table:<br/>
SRNO, COLOR, SHAPE, TEXT<br/>
1, Red, CIRCLE, "Jayesh Bhoyar"<br/>
2, Green, CIRCLE, "Sachin Tendulkar"<br/>
3, Red, CIRCLE, "DHONI"<br/>
4, Red, Square, "DRAVID"<br/>
5, Red, Square, "GANGULY"<br/>
6, Green, Square, "Rohit Sharma"<br/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me.

select?q={!tag=dt1}color:red&fq={!tag=dt2}shape:*&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=dt1}color&facet.field={!ex=dt2}shape

Answer (score 0):

Try

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q={!tag=dt1}color:red&fq={!tag=dt2}shape:*&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=dt1}color&facet.field={!ex=dt2}shape`

Comment: Thanks Arun,
Your solution worked for me for "/select" but I want to use "/browse" then how should I do configuration in XML file or in browse.vm so that to reflect these changes

Comment: Hi Arun,
Thanks the solution worked for me for "/browse" page as well.
However One problem that I have now is that I could not be able to see the results for color=red or color=green. 
As Solr is not forming the correct query. Any poniters on this.

Comment: What was your query for color=red or color=green?

Comment: #macro(url_for_facet_filter $field $value)#url_for_home#lens&fq=$esc.url('{!tag=dt1}')$esc.url($field):%22$esc.url($value)%22#end